# ivygen : where is the ivy panel?

Tags: interface

Newby question / Blender 2.75a

Suppose I add some ivy to the cube of the default scene. A panel dedicated to the "ivygen" addon appears on the left. If I modify the material of the ivy, this pannel suddendly disappears, being replaced by a "New material" pannel.

How may I go back to the "IvyGen" pannel ?

Comment: Many panels disappear when you complete a creation operation and begin other operations.  For example add sphere panel will disappear if you go into edit mode.  Some panels may remember you last setting if you begin a new creation operation.  This fact may seem not so concerning in the future.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger : thank you. So, is there anything to do to get the "ivygen" pannel back ?

Comment: Create a new ivy.  Press the letter T for Tool Shelf and letter N for properties.  Consider creation and modification as progression of time.  You can not turn back the hands of time.  Delete the old ivy and create a new one.  Perhaps the old settings will be there.  An image placed in your question will help people to understand your time investment in the ivy.  If the time investment was small create a new ivy.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger : thank you very much.